# Changing windows user in Java

Tags: java, command-line, vps

Is it possible to set a different windows user with Java?
I have following issue:

My application executes written program as admin. However, at one point I need to switch windows user in order to execute program from the command line (this program can only be accessed by this user - I cannot start it as admin due to its license).

So to simplify explanation i need to do following things:

1. start program as admin
2. login at one point as different user
3. execute program from command line
4. logout from user, login as admin
5. continue to execute program till the end

I did everything except logged in as user. Program runs on vps server.

I was googling but couldn't find the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux we have `su` for this,

[I am not sure about windows but this blog seems doing it.](http://lifehacker.com/290435/switch-user-accounts-from-the-command-prompt)

further

here is code snippet to execute native commands from java

```
try {
    // Execute a command without arguments
    String command = "dir";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Execute a command with an argument
    command = "dir";
    child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

[Source](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html)

Comment: blog helped ;) i know the code for running native commands but did not know how to switch to a different user :) tnx alot!