# java-running executable with admin privilege

Tags: java

How to call executable bat file  with admin privilege from java program ? That executable is in another directory.

Comment: I tried the SO search "run as windows admin java" and found several answers already posted on this very subject.  If the existing answers don't resolve the issue please post a very specific question with what is not working and what you have tried.

Comment: [This will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183438/changing-windows-user-in-java/4183477#4183477)

Comment: please don't ask for replies ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You need use the [runas](http://www.computerhope.com/runas.htm) command. Something like the following:

```
Runtime.exec("runas /user:ROOTUSERNAME c:\yourdir\yourbat.bat");
```

Of course, the windows ROOTUSERNAME user must have admin priviledge.

P.S.: I don't know why people voted this question down, it is a valid one...

Comment: i want to run some command like "peach.bat peachpit.xml" how to pass arguments like option filename ?

Comment: You can add them to the string when calling Runtime.exec. If it is data, you first need to save it on file, then pass the location to your bat in the command line.