# Change Computer password using java code

Tags: java

I applied following codes to change my Computer password but it didn't work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net user admin password");
}
```

I applied this "net user admin password" in command prompt as administrator and it worked.
I think i need administrator permission to successfully run this code.Please give me solution in step by step and in details Because I'm not so good.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you writing and running your code in Eclipse?

Comment: What platform, what OS?

Comment: My os is windows 7 and i use Netbeans IDE

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [microsoft documents](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427):

> To change a user's password at the command prompt, log on as an administrator and type:
>   net user user_name * /domain

So you should run your program as administrator or have logged in as an administrator already.

Note that there is a high restriction on the user type to perform this very critical command cause you can change (or set) a password without typing the old one!!

> Non-administrators receive a "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied" error message when they attempt to change the password.

Note: As Stephen C. said you can run your command with `runas` instead of `run` but it requires to enter the password (not in the command line though) so I suggest you to run a batch file instead and run a elevated shortcut inside it, for more details look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt).

Comment: i login as an administrator in my pc but its not working

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers to "[java-running executable with admin privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662672/java-running-executable-with-admin-privilege)", the solution is to use the `runas` command to run the `net` command with elevated privilege; i.e. something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas net user admin password");
```

The Microsoft documentation for `runas` is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx).

This should only work from an admin user account.